# How to ignore some delimited text when doing Python re.sub

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to "parse" some LaTeX code. LaTeX uses some special characters such as `%`, `#`, `{`, `}` and delimits inline math environments with `$ … $`.

What I need is to escape (`\`) all special chars that are not already escaped and *are not* inside `$ … $`.

For example, for the provided entry

```
#s{o}me\%thing $ \text{a} $
```

I need to return:

```
\#s\{o\}me\%thing $ \text{a} $
```

Note that the already escaped `\%`, as well as the `\text{a}` within `$ … $`, remain untouched.

I'm using Python's `re.sub` to do that, and this way I can ignore the escaped ones, but I don't know how to ignore `$ … $` environments. My current code is:

```py
string = "#s{o}me\%thing $ \text{a} $"
re.sub(r'([^\\]?)((?:%|#|{|}|&))', r"\1\\\2", string)
# Expected output: "\#s\{o\}me\%thing $ \text{a} $"
# Actual output:   "\#s\{o\}me\%thing $ \text\{a\} $"
```

At this time, my code returns, for the example above, the following:

```
\#s\{o\}me\%thing $ \text\{a\} $
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the following solution:

```
import re
s = r"#s{o}me\%thing $ \text{a} $"
rx = r'(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)(?:(\$[^$\\]*(?:\\.[^$\\]*)*\$)|([%#{}&]))'
print ( re.sub(rx, lambda x: fr"{x.group(1)}\{x.group(3)}" if x.group(3) else fr"{x.group(1)}{x.group(2)}", s, flags=re.S) )
# => \#s\{o\}me\%thing $ \text{a} $
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/m2Dsgz)

The regex is

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)(?:(\$[^$\\]*(?:\\.[^$\\]*)*\$)|([%#{}&]))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tAdfsM/1). Details:

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `((?:\\{2})*)` - Group 1: zero or more sequences of double backslashes
- `(?:(\$[^$\\]*(?:\\.[^$\\]*)*\$)|([%#{}&]))` - either of

  - `(\$[^$\\]*(?:\\.[^$\\]*)*\$)` - Group 2: `$`, then any zero or more chars other than `\` and `$`, then zero or more occurrences of an escape sequence (`\` + any char) and then any zero or more chars other than `\` and `$`, and then a `$`
  - `|` - or
  - `([%#{}&])` - Group 3: `%`, `#`, `{`, `}` or `&`.

If Group 3 is matched, the match is replaced with Group 1 + `\` + Group 3 values, else, the results is a concatenation of Group 1 and Group 2 values.